# Set a variable to a Windows path in init file

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, string

I want to use python in spacemacs on window OS, and need to tell it where to find python shell. So I added one line of

```
(setq-default python-shell-interpreter "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython.exe")
```

to the `.spacemacs`

But when restart the spacemacs, it won't start up as spacemacs, instead it's like normal emacs without spacemacs installed. But if I remove that line, I could get the spacemacs screen, so how should I set the variable in spacemacs init file?

```
(defun dotspacemacs/init ()
  "Initialization function.
This function is called at the very startup of Spacemacs initialization
before layers configuration."   
  ;; This setq-default sexp is an exhaustive list of all the supported  
  ;; spacemacs settings.   
  dotspacemacs-default-package-repository nil)  
 ;; User initialization goes here   
(setq-default python-shell-interpreter "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython.exe")
)
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting tool (`{}` button or C-k key combination) to format code, not the quote tool which messes up line breaks and interprets special characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp, backslashes inside strings start escape sequences.  For example, `\n` means a newline, and `\a` means a bell character.

If a string contains an unknown escape sequence, an error is signalled. `\A` is an unknown escape sequence, and it seems like this leads to the rest of the init file not being loaded.

You can either specify the path with forward slashes:

```
(setq-default python-shell-interpreter "C:/Anaconda/Scripts/ipython.exe")
```

or escape the backslashes with another backslash:

```
(setq-default python-shell-interpreter "C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\ipython.exe")
```